exploded pie chart, circumscribing arc, and text labels
Most of my figures in various books are pgf/tikz, with a few pstricks tossed. One of the few figures I rendered external to LaTeX (generated using a vector-based graphics program) looks like the following:

I made a few attempts to generate the equivalent using tikz, but my MWE (below) has enough 'kludges' that I'm guessing (hoping?) there must be a better way. I start with an exploded pie chart (using pgf-pie), add a dashed arc around it, and then a few tricks to annotate the arc. I ended up having to brute-force xshift and yshift in a few places, but only because I don't know a more elegant way to get there from here. Works, but I'm hoping someone can suggest a more refined approach to generate the figure.
Here is the MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf-pie}

\usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc,arrows.meta}
  \tikzset{state/.style={circle,draw=black, very thick,minimum size=4em}}

\begin{document}

\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,font=\sffamily]
 \pie[sum=100, hide number,rotate=117.5, text=inside, radius=3, explode={0.2,0},color={black!20,green!40!black!20}]
  {
   85/non-breeding\\season, 
   15/breeding\\season
  }
 \draw[>=Triangle,dashed,black,|<-|, yshift=-0.225cm] (117.5:3.25) 
 arc(117.5:422.5:3.25) node[align=right,yshift=0.715cm,xshift=0.5cm] {\emph{post}-breeding\\census~~~~~};
 \path (422.5:3.25) arc(422.5:1172.5:3.25) 
 node[align=right,xshift=-1.75cm,yshift=0.2cm] {\emph{pre}-breeding\\census~~~~~};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

Again, this MWE works, generating the following figure, but I'm guessing there must be a better way. Thanks in advance!


The answer below uses the wheelchart package, which I wrote.
The arc is drawn with the key arc. The positioning of this arc is specified with the key arc sep.
The first slice is shifted with the key explode.
The style of the slices is determined by the key slices style.
The starting angle is determined by the key start half.
The additional text is placed with 2 nodes. Here the command \WCpoint is used to position these nodes.
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\sffamily
\wheelchart[
  arc{2}={|->|,>=Triangle,dashed,thick},
  arc sep=0.25,
  data=,
  explode{1},
  pie,
  slices style={\WCvarB,draw=black,thick},
  start half,
  wheel data=\WCvarC,
  wheel data pos{list}={0.75,0.25},
  wheel data style={align=center}
]{%
  15/green!40!black!20/breeding\\season,
  85/black!20/non-breeding\\season%
}
\node[align=center] at (\WCpoint[2]{0}{0}{1}{1.2}) {\emph{post}-breeding\\census};
\node[align=center] at (\WCpoint[2]{1}{0}{1}{1.2}) {\emph{pre}-breeding\\census};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



I will admit I did have a brief look at wheelchart, but was trying to balance the flexibility of your package with the learning curve, and what I already knew how to do with pgf-tikz. But, I'm now motivated to have another look.

So, curious (without reading the wheelchart doc). Any reason why 'centering' your tikz code causes a compilation failure (compiles fine without centering)? I've tried both \begin{center}...\end{center}, and {\centering...}, but in either case, throws an error (in theory, at the final }). I've tried different document classes, without success. Perhaps its just a MikTeX thing? Error with straight LaTeX compile, PDFlatex, XeLaTeX...

@Johnny Canuck Thank you for mentioning this. I noticed this issue as well. For now, a solution is to place
\ExplSyntaxOn \cs_set_protected:Npn \__wheelchart_if_text:nn #1#2   {     \begin { pgfinterruptpicture }       \DeclareDocumentCommand \\ { o } {}       \hbox_gset:Nn \g__wheelchart_if_text_box { \pgfkeysvalueof { / wheelchart / #1 } }     \end { pgfinterruptpicture }     \dim_compare:nNnT { \box_wd:N \g__wheelchart_if_text_box } > { 0 pt }       { {#2} }   } \ExplSyntaxOff after \usepackage{wheelchart}. I will incorporate this solution in the next version of the package.

Well, at least it was an 'error' owing to anything on my end. Thanks for the 'fix'.

@JohnnyCanuck The new version 4.0 of the wheelchart package has been uploaded to CTAN in which the above issue is solved. Thus the solution above is not necessary anymore.

@matexmatix Many thanks. I'll give it a try once its available on CTAN. Your 'in place' fix actually worked fine.

Just for fun, here is an option looking for the most similar result with the minimum code and basic tikz commands that I know.
RESULT:

MWE:
\documentclass[border=0pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\definecolor{color1}{HTML}{9CD2AF}
\definecolor{color2}{HTML}{E5E6E7}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        x=1em,
        y=1em,
        >={Stealth[inset=0.05em,length=0.5em]},
        font=\sf
        ]
        \def\RAD{7.5}
        \def\OP{25}
        \def\SHIFT{0.5}
        \draw[fill=color2,thick](0,0)
            --(90-\OP:\RAD)
            arc(90-\OP:90-360+\OP:\RAD)
            -- cycle;
        \draw[fill=color1,thick](0,\SHIFT*1.5)
            -- +(90-\OP:\RAD)
            arc(90-\OP:90+\OP:\RAD)
            -- cycle;
        \draw[|->, densely dotted,thick](90-\OP:\RAD+\SHIFT)
            arc(90-\OP:90-360+\OP:\RAD+\SHIFT);
        \draw(0,-\RAD*0.4) node[align=center] {non-breeding \\ season};
        \draw(0,\RAD*0.8) node[align=center] {breeding \\ season};
        \draw(90+\OP:\RAD*1.4) node[align=center] {\emph{Pre}-breeding \\ census};
        \draw(90-\OP:\RAD*1.4) node[align=center] {\emph{Post}-breeding \\ census}; 
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}


You are just missing the little flat line at the end of the arrow.  This is a great answer.

Indeed -- it is a very 'slick' (from the Latin) approach to the problem. I suppose the only limit for the 'casual user' is that if forces them to remember basic trigonometry. Radians and circles and all that...

On the other hand, this approach makes it really easy to position/size...everything (whereas pgf-pie doesn't. wheelchart does, though). At least 'easy' once I remembered some basics about circles and radians. ;-)

@Simd , yeah, with a lot of emphasis on leaving it the same and in the end I forgot that detail.

@JohnnyCanuck , well maybe I should have used better mnemonics since it is only the use of polar coordinates that are perfect for drawing circles and ellipses, and they are so intuitive if we talk about parametric drawing and tikz uses a lot of this to simplify the positioning of everything. and relative positioning

No need to call tikz, which is already called by pgf-pie.
make explode={0,0.2} instead of explode={0.2,0} since this raises the small sector which allows the centre of the circle to be kept on the large sector. This avoids having to move the arc afterwards.
To place the node, simply use the above left and above right parameters.
And as @Teepeemm pointed out in a comment
align center removes the tildes ~~~~~ from the nodes.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc,arrows.meta}
\tikzset{state/.style={circle,draw=black, very thick,minimum size=4em}}

\begin{document}

{\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,font=\sffamily]
 \pie[sum=100, hide number,rotate=117.5, text=inside, radius=3, explode={0,0.2},color={black!20,green!40!black!20}]
  {
   85/non-breeding\\season, 
   15/breeding\\season
  }
 \draw[>=Triangle,dashed,black,|->|] (62.5:3.2)node[align=center,above right] {\emph{pre}-breeding\\census}
 arc[start angle=62.5,delta angle=-305,radius=3.2cm] 
 node[above left,align=center] {\emph{post}-breeding\\census} ;
\end{tikzpicture}

}
\end{document}



Oh yes, I hadn't noticed those tildes ~~~~~! Thank you for that.

Indeed -- thanks. I hadn't realized that there was some utility in the ordering of sectors -- specifically, where the centre of the circle was.  As you spotted, my original ordering forced me to kludge things to get it to work.
